# If the spectral radius of matrix $A$ is less than $1$, how to construct a positive definite $Q$ such that $Q - A^{H}QA$ is also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-radius

It is relatively easy to prove that if there exists a positive definite matrix $Q$ such that $Q - A^{H}QA$ is positive definite, where $A^{H}$ means the conjugate transpose of $A$, then the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$. Just look at every eigenpair $(v,\lambda)$. But as for the reverse problem, I am wondering how to construct a $Q$ such that $Q - A^{H}QA$ is positive definite, when  the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Please note that it is possible - and strongly encouraged - to use LaTeX typesetting in your posts to enhance readability. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Regarding your question: Just take your favourite positive definite matrix $P$ and define $Q := \sum_{k=0}^\infty (A^H)^k P A^k$. Then $Q$ is positive definite and satisfies $Q - A^H Q A = P$. This is a standard argument in systems and control theory; see for instance Section 3.3.5 in [this book](https://zbmath.org/1074.93003).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Please do not use comments to post answers.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, I usually don't do this - but the question is clearly not research level, so I'm a bit reluctant to post an answer to it. (The proper process would, of course, have been to vote to close, and suggest to the OP to post the question on Math StackExchange. But since the answer is just two lines and I knew it off my head, it felt somehow unfair towards the OP to not even mention the solution.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Jochen, I do not see why the series converges under the only hypothesis that the spectral radius is less than one. Is this the content of the section in the book you indicated or I miss something simple?

Comment: @Jochen Glueck Thank you very much. Now I can understand the "magic" construction of Q. And I really appreciate your helping me edit my question.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  (I am afraid my English expression could be inappropriate or unclear at times.)  You can try to take a norm such that ||A|| is less than 1.  Matrix Analysis by Roger and Charles may be helpful. You can find information about the connection between spectral radius and matrix norm, as well as the convergence of matrix series in that book.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: If $r(A) < 1$, choose a number $\delta \in (r(A),1)$. Then there exists a number $M \ge 1$ such that $\|A^k\| \le M \delta^k$ for each integer $k \ge 0$; this implies the convergence. Alternatively, one can use the renorming trick pointed out by Kevin. (So one doesn't need the book for the argument; I was just referring to the book to provide Kevin with a standard reference about the topic).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you, I missed the elementary estimate.

Comment: @JochenGlueck This question has presently no close votes, 3 upvotes and no downvotes. Therefore, I don't see a reason not to post a proper answer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If you like, you can post a CW answer along the lines of Jochen Glueck's comment.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Ok, I did as Federico Poloni and you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll follow the suggestions in the comments and post my comment as an answer:

Take your favourite positive definite matrix $P$ and define $Q := \sum_{k=0}^\infty (A^{\operatorname{H}})^k P A^k$; note that this series converges since, as the spectral radius of $A$ is $<1$, there exist numbers $\delta \in [0,1)$ and $M \ge 1$ such that $\|A^k\| \le M \delta^k$ for all integers $k \ge 0$.
The matrix $Q$ is positive definite and satisfies $Q−A^{\operatorname{H}}QA=P$.

*Remarks:*

- Both the result and the proof above are standard in systems and control theory; see for instance Section 3.3.5 in the book *Mathematical systems theory. I. Modelling, state space analysis, stability and robustness* (2005) by Hinrichsen and Pritchard ([link to zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/1074.93003)).
- The same argument also works for bounded linear operators on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.